# Iterating *ngFor in Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to iterate an array using ***ngFor**, but it's not working. below is my code.

[My API Data showing like this in console widow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWRhP.png)

**TypeScript Code**

```
  tailors: Tailors[] = [];

  getTailors() {
    this.tailorService.getTailors().subscribe(x => {
      Object.assign(this.tailors, x);
      console.log(x);
    });
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-item class="animate__animated animate__fadeInUp" *ngFor="let tailor of tailors">
  <div class="item_inner d-flex">
   
    <div class="text_box">
      <h3>{{tailor.data.Name}}</h3>
    
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bounded property in the `*ngFor` is an object literal not an array. You have to loop through `tailors['data']`.

I assume you have an error stating  **"NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays"**.

Your code in the template should be

```
*ngFor="let tailor of tailors['data']"
```

Or better when you assign the backend response inside the `.ts` you bind the tailors to `x['data']` and then you do not need to change anything in the template.

PS: I do not see a need of your usage of `Object.assign()`. Also include errors  in your next posts to help people help you.

Comment: Thanks for your supoort. This solution worked and I tried in my backend(ts) that also worked.,